# Python 2.7 download images

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using python 2.7 and pycharm is my editor. What i'm trying to do is have python go to a site and download an image from that site and save it to my directory. Currently I have no errors but i don't think its downloading because the file is not showing in my directory.

```
import random
import urllib2

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib2.Request(url, full_name)

download_web_image("www.example.com/page1/picture.jpg")
```

Comment: try to use an absolute path for image

Comment: But should `urllib2.Request` save the contents?

Comment: you need to write the object to a file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to save image from web using urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439809/unable-to-save-image-from-web-using-urllib2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply creating a `Request` but you are not downloading the image. Try the following instead:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), full_name)) # download and save image
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 so i have to use urllib2

Comment: `urllib` is contained in both versions of Python. In fact, I'm using 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick. The rest can stay the same, just edit your function to include the two lines I have added.

```
def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    img = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    with open (full_name, 'w') as f: f.write(img)
```

---

**Edit 1:**

Exact code as requested in comments.

```
import urllib2

def download_web_image(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    img = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    with open ('test.jpg', 'w') as f: f.write(img)

download_web_image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg")
```

Comment: Try with the image [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg) because I get a weird distortion.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi What do you mean? Works perfectly fine for me!

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed do the trick. One problem i have is that my tested image comes out distorted and green, so its probably something with the image itself, i'm going to try other images to see if it works.

Comment: @jumpman8947 Odd, it works for me, looks like it is supposed to. Just to confirm, brown leaves, grey stone, bit of green grass top left and bottom right.

Comment: @Felix_Sim It still is distorted, both blocks of code.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Then I do not know. I cannot reproduce any distortion or colour problem regardless of how many times I am trying. Maybe it's the OS. I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 with Python 2.7.6.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 though I doubt it's the OS. I mean we're reading the data and writing it.

Comment: Felix_Sim, i run your exact code- it run with no problem- but where i see the download file?

Answer (score 1):

Or try the requests library:

```
import requests

image = requests.get("www.example.com/page1/picture.jpg")
with open('picture.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image.content)
```